# Web2py client device information

Tags: web2py

Is there a way to get the client device information such as the device and OS used?
I know that we can get the public IP but for device and OS type could not find any reference.

Answer (score 0):

That information is contained in the `request` global variable. All functions in controllers should have access to that. There are lots of bits of information in there but this looks closest to what you want.

```py
user_agent = request.env.http_user_agent
```